# Rails: Regx validation error - cannot read addMethod

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I have a form and I want to use regex for validation, but it gives me the following error:

(index):250 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined at HTMLDocument. ((index):250)

EDIT: I forgot to include the following lines in my javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery.validate.additional-methods
//= require jquery.validate
```

---

I am now seeing a slightly different error:

> jquery.validate.additional-methods.self-b6742ad35d3d82c2cb0ca5dc43bfffbc87063c90e0d8fd70714c5424128f408d.js?body=1:31
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined
>
> $.validator.addMethod( "maxWords", function( value, element, params )

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var messages = {
    'nameRequired': "Naam is verplicht.",
    'emailRequired': "Voer een geldig e-mailadres in.",
    'bodyRequired': "Bericht is verplicht."
  };

  $.validator.addMethod("regx", function(value, element, regexpr) {
    return regexpr.test(value);
  });

  $('#new_message').validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        regex: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        regex: /^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/
      },
      body: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        regex: /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/
      },
    },
    messages: {
      name: messages.nameRequired,
      email: messages.emailRequired,
      body: messages.bodyRequired
    },
    onfocusout: function(element) {
      this.element(element);
    },
  });
});
```

The HTML form:

```
<%= form_for @message do | f | %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :naam %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control form__field small__field', required: true, name: 'name' %>
    <br />
    <%= f.label :email, 'E-mailadres' %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'form-control form__field small__field', required: true, name: 'email' %>
    <br />
    <%= f.label :bericht %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, :class => 'form-control form__field', rows: 7, cols: 72, required: true, name: 'body' %>
    <br />
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "VERSTUUR", :class => 'btn--red btn__submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Gems I used:

```
gem 'jquery-validation-rails'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: It means that there is no $.validator on the page.

Answer (score 2):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

Maybe this is helpful for someone else. I got rid of the above error by switching:

```
//= require jquery.validate.additional-methods
//= require jquery.validate
```

to:

```
//= require jquery.validate
//= require jquery.validate.additional-methods
```